# How to minimize the sum of difference of element in sub-sequence of array of length k from given sequence of length n

Tags: algorithms, dynamic-programming, linear-programming, greedy-algorithms, constraint-programming

How to minimize the sum of difference of element in sub-sequence of array of length k from given sequence of length n ?

for example : for n=10
1
2
3
4
10
20
30
40
100
200

the sub-sequence of length will with minimized sum of difference will be
1 2 3 4
as  |1-2| + |1-3| + |1-4| + |2-3| + |2-4| + |3-4| = 10 i.e minimum in any sequence.

Comment: What have you tried ? Did you get stuck somewhere ? Show us what have you done so far, then we can help you accordingly.

Comment: Must the subsequence be contiguous?

Answer (score 0):

Where are the constraints? Well, since I don't know what the constraints are, I will help you with an almost naive solution. For each segment of length `k` (so there are `n-k+1` segments) you have to order the elements, because if you have an ordered array then you can calculate that cost function of the segment as follow. For example:

```
array: 1 2 3 4
```

The cost function as you said is:

```
|1-2| + |1-3| + |1-4| + |2-3| + |2-4| + |3-4|
```

and it is equal to:

```
2-1 + 3-1 + 4-1 + 3-2 + 4-2 + 4-3 = 10
```

and it is equal to:

```
4*3 + 3*2 + 2*1 + 1*0 - 1*3 - 2*2 - 3*1 - 4*0 = 10
```

So as you can see for a general ordered array:

```
array: a0, a1, a2, ..., an-1 ; a0 <= a1 <= a2 <= a3.. <= an-2 <= an-1
```

The cost function can be calculated as:

```
an-1*(n-1) - an-1*(0) + an-2*(n-2) - an-2*(1)... + ak*k - ak*(n-1-k) + ... + a0*(0) - a0*(n-1)
```

So the time complexity for the cost function will be `O(k)`, and the total cost will be   `O((n - k + 1) * (k * logk + k)) = O(n*k*logk)`.